# Is SELinux still effective even when an attacker obtains the root shell?

Tags: selinux

I have a simple question.

I'd turn off SELinux for development. When I seriously started thinking about using it instead, I thought, well that's neat. It can restrict applications to certain jobs.

However, when an attacker obtains the root shell, is that still effective?

I mean the root can simply turn it off.

Comment: Not if that root user is in a security context that doesn't *let* them "simply turn it off". That said, those restrictions *should* be preventing an attacker from getting to root at all, if they're written appropriately -- if a process isn't allowed to execute a setuid or setgid binary, or isn't allowed to `exec()` *anything at all* (shell or otherwise), it's going to be a lot harder to get to that point.

Comment: Inasmuch as it's not about writing/developing code (as is StackOverflow's focus) and is about a tool with an audience beyond developers (sysadmins in particular come to mind), this question is a better fit for [security.se].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SELinux is still effective even if an attacker obtains a shell with "root" privileges. The reason is that the shell will be associated with the SELinux security context of the compromised process.

**If the security policy is correctly confining the parent process in its own domain**, then both processes (parent and child) will have only the SELinux permissions given for the tasks of the parent. Even with «root» DAC privileges, the child process (the shell) will be confined too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help understand and answer your question yourself:

SELinux denies acces the following way: first *DAC* is checked and if everything with the security context is OK, then *SELinux Policies* apply.

Normally accesses by the root probably won't get denied by DAC, because of the security context that the root possesses. But by design SELinux uses *hooks* associated with different kernel operations or resources that require access control assessment. These hooks are part of the kernel code and the root, just like any other user, directly or indirectly invokes kernel functions and with them, corresponding SELinux hooks get triggered and executed. They can deny access even to a root.

Yes, being root allows you to disable SELinux completely. Heck, it even allows you to rebuild the kernel and add, remove or modify functionality of SELinux and the kernel itself...so being root does not only make SELinux ineffective, but the whole kernel.

Comment: "The security context that the root possesses" depends a great deal on just how one *came* to be root. An escalation from a non-root user with a limited context will not necessarily escape that limited context, making the first sentence of the third paragraph ("It is safe to say[...]") perhaps not so safe?

Comment: Yeah what i meant is that it is rarely the case, but i think you have a good point, maybe the way i expressed it was a bit innacurate